# How to use HTTPS with PyQt4/5

Tags: python, https, pyqt

So I've got a slight issue and could use general advice. I need to build a python based web browser that's super simple (no tabs, no back, no refresh button, etc). Just need to display a page but I've tried with PyQt4 and have an http version working (QwebView) but I need to use HTTPS with Client side Certs for Authentication.

Any idea how to go about implementing this (HTTPS with Client Certs)?

Comment: Use PyQt5 with QtWebEngine, QWebView is deprecated.

Comment: Doe you know if this support HTTPS with Client Authentication using a Certificate?

Comment: What do you mean by that, if you mean that if you can see https pages, the answer is yes, otherwise it could explain what you want better.

Comment: I found the answer to my question this morning, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.